# C printf of an integer with %lu produces large number

Tags: c, int, 64-bit, printf, long-integer

I know that is bad practice to print an integer with %lu which is a unsigned long. In a project i was working on i got a large number when trying to print 11 with %lu in the snprint format.(old code) I am using gcc 4.9.3.

This code below i thought would produce the wrong number since snprintf is told to read more than the 4 bytes occupied. Its doesnt though. Works perfectly. It reads everything correctly. Either it does not go past the 4 bytes in to the unknown or the extra 4 bytes in the long are fully of zeros when it gets promoted to long from int.

I am wondering out of curiosity is when does printf print the wrong number? What conditions does it need produce a wrong big number? There has to be garbage in the upper 4 bytes but it seems like it does not set that garbage for me.

I read the answers here but the code worked for me. I know its a different compiler.

[Printing int type with %lu - C+XINU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120062/printing-int-type-with-lu-cxinu)

```
  #include<inttypes.h>
  #include<stdio.h>
    int main(void){
        uint32_t number1 = 11;
        char sentence[40];
        snprintf(sentence,40,"Small number :%lu , Big number:%lu \n",number1,285212672);
        printf(sentence);
    }
```

Comment: It's likely that `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(long)` are same on your test environment.

Answer (score 1):

On OP's machine, `uint32_t`, `unsigned long` and `int` appear to be the same size [@R Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32574554/c-printf-of-an-integer-with-lu-produces-large-number/32574761#comment53004482_32574554). OP's code is not portable and may produce incorrect output on another machine.

> when does printf print the wrong number?

Use the matching `printf()` specifier for truly portable code.  Using mis-matched specifiers *may* print the wrong number.

The output string may be well over 40 characters.  Better to use a generous or right-sized buffer.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
  uint32_t number1 = 11;
  // char sentence[40];
  char sentence[80];
  snprintf(sentence, sizeof sentence,
      "Small number :%" PRIu32 " , Big number:%d \n",
      number1, 285212672);
  // printf(sentence);  // Best not to print a string using the printf() format parameter
  fputs(sentence, stdout);
}
```